# ¿Cómo hacer que el botón de la coma de una calculadora se pueda clickear una sola vez?

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode, sublimetext3, math

Estoy creando una calculadora, con sus funcionalidades básicas. Pero hay un par de cosas que no se como hacer, y necesito ayuda.

Mi duda es en como hacer para que el botón de la coma solo se pueda clickear una sola vez, ya que si lo clickeo varias veces sigue apareciendo, y en una calculadora normal, cuando clickeas la coma, incluso si se clickea más de una vez, solamente aparece en pantalla una sola vez. El nombre de la variable del botón es "botonComa".

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.font as font

import math


root=Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")

root.resizable(0,0)


frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
frame.config(bg="grey22")

TNR=font.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=20)


operacion=""

reset_pantalla=False

resultado=0


#--------------pantallla--------------

numeroPantalla=StringVar()

reset_pantalla=True

numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado))

pantalla=Entry(frame, width=25, font=TNR, textvariable=numeroPantalla)
pantalla.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", fg="black")

#--------------pulsaciones teclado--------------

def numeroPulsado(num):

    global operacion

    global reset_pantalla

    if reset_pantalla!=False:
        
        numeroPantalla.set(num)
        
        reset_pantalla=False

    
    else:
        numeroPantalla.set(numeroPantalla.get() + num)


#--------------funcion suma--------------

def suma(num):
    
    global operacion

    global resultado

    global reset_pantalla

    resultado+=float(num)

    operacion="suma"

    reset_pantalla=True

    numeroPantalla.set(resultado)

#--------------funcion resta--------------

num1=0

contador_resta=0

def resta(num):
    
    global operacion

    global resultado

    global num1

    global contador_resta

    global reset_pantalla

    if contador_resta==0:

        num1=float(num)

        resultado=num1

    else:

        if contador_resta==1:

            resultado=num1-float(num)

        else:

            resultado=float(resultado)-float(num)   

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado)

        resultado=numeroPantalla.get()


    contador_resta+=1

    operacion="resta"

    reset_pantalla=True

#-------------funcion multiplicacion---------------------
contador_multi=0

def multiplica(num):

    global operacion

    global resultado

    global num1

    global contador_multi

    global reset_pantalla
    
    if contador_multi==0:

        num1=float(num)
        
        resultado=num1

    else:

        if contador_multi==1:

            resultado=num1*float(num)

        else:

            resultado=float(resultado)*float(num)   

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado)
        
        resultado=numeroPantalla.get()


    contador_multi+=1

    operacion="multiplicacion"

    reset_pantalla=True

#-----------------funcion division---------------------

contador_divi=0

def divide(num):

    global operacion

    global resultado

    global num1

    global contador_divi

    global reset_pantalla
    
    if contador_divi==0:

        num1=float(num)
        
        resultado=num1

    else:

        if contador_divi==1:

            resultado=num1/float(num)

        else:

            resultado=float(resultado)/float(num)   

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado)
        
        resultado=numeroPantalla.get()


    contador_divi+=1

    operacion="division"

    reset_pantalla=True

#--------------funcion potencia al cuadrado--------------

contador_potencia=0

def potencia(num):

    global operacion

    global resultado

    global num1

    global contador_potencia

    global reset_pantalla
    
    if contador_potencia==0:

        num1=float(num)
        
        resultado=num1

    else:

        if contador_potencia==1:

            resultado=num1**2

        else:

            resultado=float(resultado)**2   

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado)
        
        resultado=numeroPantalla.get()


    contador_potencia+=1

    reset_pantalla=True

    numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)**2)

    resultado=0

    contador_potencia=0

#--------------funcion raiz al cuadrado--------------

contador_raiz=0

def raiz(num):

    global operacion

    global resultado

    global num1

    global contador_raiz

    global reset_pantalla
    
    if contador_raiz==0:

        num1=float(num)
        
        resultado=num1

    else:

        if contador_raiz==1:

            resultado=math.sqrt(num1)

        else:

            resultado=float(math.sqrt(resultado))   

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado)
        
        resultado=numeroPantalla.get()


    contador_raiz+=1

    reset_pantalla=True

    numeroPantalla.set(float(math.sqrt(resultado)))

    resultado=0

    contador_raiz=0



#----------------funcion borrar----------------

def borrar():

    global resultado

    global reset_pantalla

    reset_pantalla=True

    resultado=0

    numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado))


#----------------funcion el_resultado----------------

def el_resultado():

    global resultado

    global operacion

    global contador_resta

    global contador_multi

    global contador_divi
    

    if operacion=="suma":

        numeroPantalla.set(resultado+float(numeroPantalla.get()))

        resultado=0

    elif operacion=="resta":

        numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)-float(numeroPantalla.get()))

        resultado=0

        contador_resta=0

    elif operacion=="multiplicacion":

        numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)*float(numeroPantalla.get()))

        resultado=0

        contador_multi=0

    elif operacion=="division":

        numeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)/float(numeroPantalla.get()))

        resultado=0

        contador_divi=0


#--------------fila 1--------------

botonRaizCuadrada=Button(frame, text="X^(1/2)", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:raiz(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonRaizCuadrada.grid(row=2, column=1)

botonPotenciaCuadrado=Button(frame, text="X^2", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:potencia(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonPotenciaCuadrado.grid(row=2, column=2)

botonBorrarUltimoDigito=Button(frame, text="DEL", width=5, font=TNR)
botonBorrarUltimoDigito.grid(row=2, column=3)

botonBorrarTodo=Button(frame, text="C", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:borrar())
botonBorrarTodo.grid(row=2, column=4)
botonBorrarTodo.config(bg="grey22", fg="red")

#--------------fila 1--------------

boton7=Button(frame, text="7", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("7"))
boton7.grid(row=3, column=1)
boton7.config(fg="sandy brown")

boton8=Button(frame, text="8", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("8"))
boton8.grid(row=3, column=2)
boton8.config(fg="magenta2")

boton9=Button(frame, text="9", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("9"))
boton9.grid(row=3, column=3)
boton9.config(fg="saddle brown")

botonDividir=Button(frame, text="÷", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:divide(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonDividir.grid(row=3, column=4)

#--------------fila 2--------------

boton4=Button(frame, text="4", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("4"))
boton4.grid(row=4, column=1)
boton4.config(fg="cyan2")

boton5=Button(frame, text="5", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("5"))
boton5.grid(row=4, column=2)
boton5.config(fg="gold2")

boton6=Button(frame, text="6", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("6"))
boton6.grid(row=4, column=3)
boton6.config(fg="purple")

botonMultiplicar=Button(frame, text="X", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:multiplica(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonMultiplicar.grid(row=4, column=4)

#--------------fila 3--------------

boton1=Button(frame, text="1", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("1"))
boton1.grid(row=5, column=1)
boton1.config(fg="deep pink")

boton2=Button(frame, text="2", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("2"))
boton2.grid(row=5, column=2)
boton2.config(fg="blue")

boton3=Button(frame, text="3", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("3"))
boton3.grid(row=5, column=3)
boton3.config(fg="green")

botonRestar=Button(frame, text="-", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:resta(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonRestar.grid(row=5, column=4)

#--------------fila 4--------------

botonComa=Button(frame, text=",", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado(","))
botonComa.grid(row=6, column=1)

boton0=Button(frame, text="0", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:numeroPulsado("0"))
boton0.grid(row=6, column=2)

botonIgual=Button(frame, text="=", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:el_resultado())
botonIgual.grid(row=6, column=3)
botonIgual.config(bg="grey22", fg="red")

botonSumar=Button(frame, text="+", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:suma(numeroPantalla.get()))
botonSumar.grid(row=6, column=4)


#--------------fin--------------

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, deberías valorar si utilizarás coma o punto, pero teniendo en cuenta que trabajarás con float:

```
def numeroPulsado(num):
    global reset_pantalla
    texto=numeroPantalla.get()
    if num == ",":
        cant_comas = texto.count(",")
        cant_puntos = texto.count(".")
        if cant_comas >= 1 or cant_puntos >= 1 or len(texto)==0:
            return
    if reset_pantalla!=False:
        numeroPantalla.set('.' if num==',' else num)
        reset_pantalla=False
    else:
        numeroPantalla.set(texto + ('.' if num==',' else num))
```

Esto permite que si se da clic en `,`, entonces se verifica si ya existe más de una coma y se retorna, en caso positivo, sin permitir continuar con el resto del código. Cuando modifiques el valor del `StringVar`, pudieras utilizar `'.' if num==',' else num`, para evitar problemas a la hora de calcular, porque lanzaría una excepción cuando intentes hacerle el cast a `float`.

Para eliminar el último valor, agregas el `command`:

```
botonBorrarUltimoDigito=Button(frame, text="C", width=5, font=TNR, command=lambda:borrar_ultimo())
```

Para borrarlo podrías, entre otras cosas, modificar el valor del `StringVar` eliminando el último caracter del string:

```
def borrar_ultimo():
    texto=numeroPantalla.get()
    numeroPantalla.set(texto[:len(texto) - 1])
```

Comment: en lugar de no hacer nada si no hay texto cabe la opción de que se comvierta en 0,xxx

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has ayudado mucho, saludos Firefly!